# Parameter passing of self defined class object in python: call-by-reference or call-by-value evaluation?

Tags: python, parameter-passing

When you call 'append' with a list, the pointer of the list is passed in, so the original data is changed.

```
>>> tmp = [1,2]
>>> tmp.append(3)
>>> tmp
[1, 2, 3]
```

Here comes my question. For the following code, when I pass the Node object named 'head' into the method 'get', I expect that head would point to the second node with value 2 after calling the method. However, it turns out that 'head' is still pointing to the first node with value 1.

```
>>> class Node:    
        def __init__(self, val):
            self.val  = val
            self.next = None    
        def get(self, index):
            for i in range(index):
                self = self.next
            return self.val

>>> head = Node(1)
>>> head.next = Node(2)
>>> head.get(1)
2
>>> head.val
1
```

Can anyone explain why is this happening? To my understanding, as Node is mutable, a reference should be passed in. How can I know whether a reference or value is passed in? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python passes the value of a reference to an object when making a call instead of actually passing the object reference itself. In this case, `self` is just a local variable with a copy of a reference to the `Node` object that the `get` method is bound to, so if you assign to `self` with something else (`self.next` in your case), all that happens is for the local variable `self` to hold a reference to a different object, but the object that `self` originally referred to, as well as the reference to the object from the caller, remains untouched.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Clear to me now.

Comment: "Python is neither call-by-value nor call-by-reference. Instead, it passes the value of a reference when making a call." That is exactly pass-by-value. Every value in Python (every variable, the result of evaluating any expression, etc.) is a reference, and when you pass a value, i.e. a reference, it is passed by value. The semantics of passing and assigning in Python are identical to Java, and Java is universally called pass-by-value.

Comment: link to the Java semantics question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: @newacct Indeed. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @newacct these semantics are technically called ["call by sharing", or "call by object sharing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to @blhsing, you're doing local reassignment (nothing to do with call-by-value or reference), and you can verify this with:

```
a1 = [1]
def expand(a):
    a = a + [2]
    return a
a2 = expand(a1)
print(a1) # prints [1]
print(a2) # prints [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It does make sense to me that `expand` won't change the original list, but why can `append` method modify the original list? @blhsing @iamanigeeit

Comment: As previous commenters have mentioned, Python is passing a reference to the original list, and since list is mutable, you can modify it. It wouldn't make sense to copy a 1000000-item list every time you want a function to add to it.

Comment: @Xinming Might be a late comment, because that's what the `append` method is intended to do.  `self = self.next` is an assignment statement, it doesn't modify the node object `self` references to, that's why `head.val` is still `1`. What actually happens is variable `self` is reassigned another node object that was originally referenced by `self.next`. So yeah, the `head` (`Node(1)`) won't become `Node(2)` as you might want.